# Angular ui-grid editable feature should work on one click only

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Here is the tutorial link for angular ui-grid editable feature [Angular ui-grid editable tutorial link](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable).

As per the tutorial/ official plnkr of editable ui-grid feature, editable rows/fields can be edited only when user double-clicks on it.

Which approach should I follow to make the rows/field editable only on single click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is additional functionality which I come to know [Rows/field editable with one click](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/309_editable_with_cellnav) . Cells or fields will be editable on one click too